# Shell: searching for a pattern in a file and extracting a data block which contains the pattern

Tags: shell, sed, grep

Given is a file with the following structure:

```
a 123
b 876234
c 56456
d 65765

a 9879
b 9361
c 6527
d 823468
```

So there are blocks of data (lines beginning with `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and an empty line divides two blocks) and I'm looking for a pattern (e.g. 9361) inside this file. If this pattern is found inside I want to copy the whole block (line starting with `a 9879` and ending with `d 823468`) and write it to another file.

This pattern can be found zero or more times inside a file. If there are more than one results each block should be written to the other file.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with gawk.

```
gawk 'BEGIN {RS=""} /here goes your pattern/ { print $0}' INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE
```

This sets gawk's record separator to the empty line(s).

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in file.txt, this is a solution in perl.

```
perl -00 -ne "print if /9361/" file.txt
```

The result is on stdout.

- `-00` causes perl to read the file a paragraph at a time.
- `-n` causes perl to read filename arguments one by one.
- `-e` is to specify a perl command.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.8+)

```
ruby -00 -ne 'print if /9361/' file
```